# Wizard django 2.1 : __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I use Django 2.1, I installed form tools, and I used the wizard module, the goal is to create a stepbystep page with several forms.

I dont know if  I have to change something, but I already lookup on other post, but unfortunatly I didnt solve my problem.

I have this error :

```
TypeError at /dashboard/createproject/

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/dashboard/createproject/
Django Version:     2.1.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:     /home/user/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 21
Python Executable:  /home/user/Desktop/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.7
Python Path:    

['/home/user/Desktop',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/user/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.1.0-py3.6.egg']

Server time:    jeu, 31 Jan 2019 12:02:24 +0100
```

Comment: Inside of `urlpatterns` use `views.FormWizard()` instead of `views.FormWizard`

Comment: It is a class-based view, so you should write `path('createproject/', views.FormWizard.as_view(), ...)`, not `views.FormWizard` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Django forms does not allow positional arguments starting from 2.0 as it is documented as follows.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-2-0

> Form fields no longer accept optional arguments as positional arguments
>   To help prevent runtime errors due to incorrect ordering of form field arguments, optional arguments of built-in form fields are no longer accepted as positional arguments. For example:

```
forms.IntegerField(25, 10)
```

> raises an exception and should be replaced with:

```
forms.IntegerField(max_value=25, min_value=10)
```